# how to use upper_bound to find out the last variable that satisfies a certain condition

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm trying to use a log(n) method to find out the last variable that satisfies a certain condition. I looked at the documentation and found
these in the algorithm section (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

Binary search (operating on partitioned/sorted ranges):

lower_bound: Return iterator to lower bound (function template )

upper_bound: Return iterator to upper bound (function template )

equal_range: Get subrange of equal elements (function template )

binary_search: Test if value exists in sorted sequence (function template )

I think to do what I'm trying to do, I should use upper_bound/lower_bound.

In this case, I'm trying to find out the last index of the number that is smaller or equal to 3. (3). I know there are simpler ways such as looping through the whole array, but I want to learn how to use upper_bound. I know that the comparator needs 2 numbers but I don't need 2 numbers so I'm not sure what to do.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
bool check(int base) {
    if (a.at(base)  <= 3) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int c;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    c = distance(a.begin(), upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), check));
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

How would I correctly do this?

Answer (score 1):

The comparator compares the number you are searching for `3` with the numbers in the vector. That's why it needs two parameters. You've hard coded the number `3` in your comparator, when you are supposed to pass it as an argument to `upper_bound`.

It's also the function that orders the vector, so if you are going to use one, you should also pass it to `sort`.

Your code could look like this

```
bool check(int x, int y) {
    return x < y;
}

int main() {
    int c;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), check);
    c = distance(a.begin(), upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), 3, check));
}
```

But since in this case `check` is just the default less-than operation, you can leave it out completely.

```
int main() {
    int c;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    c = distance(a.begin(), upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), 3));
}
```

See reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)

Comment: is 3 the value for x or y?

Comment: @RonaldLiu It's `x`. But note that it must be a *less than* operator. It should be true if x would be placed before y in your sorted vector, and false otherwise.